# How to track 404 error without using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

Here is a simple code to play an audio file and resolve the promise after the audio is finished:

```js
// our function
function audioPlay(source){

  let audio = new Audio(`${source}`);
  audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  audio.play();
  
  return new Promise((resolve) => {

  audio.addEventListener("ended", function(){  
  audio.currentTime = 0;          
  resolve();          
  }); 

  }); 
}

// play the audio after 3 seconds
setTimeout(() => play(), 3000);

// I created this function to show that resolving is working
async function play(){
 
     await audioPlay('myAudio.mp3');
     console.log('Resolved correctly..');

}
```

**First Scenario**: The audio source is correct the audio plays and at the end of it the promise resolves and we see the `console.log('Resolved correctly..');`

**Second Scenario**: The source is not correct (there is not such a file) then we have these errors:

> GET https://example.com/play/myAudio.mp3 404
>
> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no
>   supported source was found.

I want to track the second scenario, to be more clear I want to track 404 error. Why?

Because I want to play another audio like a beep sound if there is not an audio file with the given source.

Is there any solutions? Please help...

Note: I know we can check file existence using a function like this:

```
function fileExist(url) {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {   

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('HEAD', url, true);

        xhr.onload = function () {
        return resolve(xhr.status==200)
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
         return resolve(xhr.status==200)
      };

        xhr.send();

    });

}
```

But I'm looking for tracking 404 error here. This function should be the last option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add error handler to it

```js
function audioPlay(source) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let audio = new Audio(`${source}`);
    audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    audio.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
      resolve({ error: e, mediaError: audio.error })
    })
    audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
      audio.currentTime = 0;
      resolve({ complete: true });
    });
    audio.play();
  });
}

// play the audio after 3 seconds
setTimeout(() => play(), 3000);

// I created this function to show that resolving is working
async function play() {

  const result = await audioPlay('myAudio.mp3');
  if (result.error) {
    console.log(result.mediaError)
  } else {
    console.log('Resolved correctly..');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping `await` in a `try ... catch`. I think that should work.